# Why nan values are shown after reindexing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to reindex the columns, but it's displaying nan values. I am not able to understand why?

```
data = {
    "age": [50, 40, 30, 40],
    "qualified": [True, False, False, False]
    }
index = ["P", "Q", "R", "S"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

new = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
newdf = df.reindex(new)
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
   age qualified
A  NaN       NaN
B  NaN       NaN
C  NaN       NaN
D  NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), with nested list if need replace index values by new values:

```
new = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
newdf = df.set_index([new])
#alternative
#newdf.index = new
print(newdf)
   age  qualified
A   50       True
B   40      False
C   30      False
D   40      False
```

---

Method [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) working different - it create new index by list with alignment data - it means first match existing values of index by values of new list `new` and for not matching values create `NaN`s:

```
data = {
    "age": [50, 40, 30, 40],
    "qualified": [True, False, False, False]
    }
index = ["A", "Q", "D", "C"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

new = ["A", "B", "C"]
newdf = df.reindex(new)
print(newdf)

    age qualified
A  50.0      True
B   NaN       NaN
C  40.0     False
```